# Join[] messes with the parameters to SendMail[]

Tags: associations, email

I am looking to have a program that can shift between a few different email accounts and am personally storing credentials. I noticed that:

```
    SendMail[<|"To" -> "***@***.***",
 "Subject" -> "SubjectForEmail",
  "Body" -> "SomeText", "From" -> "***@***.**", 
 "Server" -> "smtp.***.***", "UserName" -> "***@***.**", 
  "Password" -> "***", "PortNumber" -> 587, 
 "EncryptionProtocol" -> "StartTLS"|>]
```

Works great. However:

```
    SendMail[Join[<|"To" -> "***@***.***",
  "Subject" -> "SubjectForEmail",
  "Body" -> "SomeText", "From" -> "***@***.**", 
 "Server" -> "smtp.***.***", "UserName" -> "***@***.**", 
  "Password" -> "***", "PortNumber" -> 587, 
  "EncryptionProtocol" -> "StartTLS"|>]]
```

Fails every time and asks for me to sign in with a Wolfram account (obviously ignoring the parameters that it was given)

Note:

```
Join[<||>]//Head
```

-> Association

```
<||>//Head
```

-> Association

It's the same type and has the same contents. SendMail[] just doesn't like it after it is Join[]ed.

Have I missed something in the SendMail[] or Join[] documentation? Is this something special about Associations?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

After goofing around with this, I figured out that `SendMail[#]& @ Join[<|...|>]` works for some reason. (Note: `SendMail @ Join[<|...|>]` does not work)

I'm not marking this as answered yet because I have absolutely no idea why this solution works and would appreciate any insight you might have.

Comment: What happens if you use `Identity` instead of `Join` ? What happens if you do `SendMail[Evaluate[Join[...]]]` ?

Comment: No luck with `Identity` but `SendMail[Evaluate[Join[...]]]` seems to work. I think that solves it. I had no idea that SendMail[] might hold the evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that SendMail[...] holds the evaluation until later. To counteract this, use the pure function that I suggested in my post or use the solution proposed by flinty which is `SendMail[Evaluate[Join[...]]]`

Comment: I suspected this much. It's a shame the documentation  of SendMail doesn't seem to mention it anywhere.